# How to XZ compress directory WITHOUT tar?

Tags: xz

I know how to compress a directory with xz using tar, but is it possible to compress a directory using xz WITHOUT tar?

If I try:

```
xz -z myDir
```

Then the following error is retured:

```
xz: myDir: Is a directory, skipping
```

Comment: You could use `7z`. The world doesn't revolve around XZ.

Comment: Unfortunately, 7z isn't available to me,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xz`, like `compress`, `gzip` and other Unix-style compressors, is a single-file compressor: it outputs `.xz` files which are always decompressed to a single file.

Because of that, compressing directories or multiple files requires a container of some sort (if you want to be able to recover the separate files). That’s typically a `tar` archive, but it could be a `cpio` archive or some other format.